# JavaScript equivalent of python string slicing

Tags: javascript, python, string, slice

Is there a JavaScript equivalent to this Python method of string slicing?

```py
>>> 'stackoverflow'[1:]
'tackoverflow'
```

I have tried:

```js
// this crashes
console.log("stackoverflow".slice(1,));

// output doesn't print the last letter 'w'
console.log("stackoverflow".slice(1, -1));
// tackoverflo
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply use `s2.slice(1)` without the comma.

Comment: To be precise , syntax is object.slice(start, end)

Answer (score 8):

See [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [`String.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).

```js
'1234567890'.slice(1, -1);            // String
'1234567890'.split('').slice(1, -1);  // Array
```

---

However, Python slices have steps:

```py
'1234567890'[1:-1:2]
```

But `*.prototype.slice` has no `step` parameter. To remedy this, I wrote [`slice.js`](https://github.com/hustcc/slice.js). To install:

```sh
npm install --save slice.js
```

Example usage:

```js
import slice from 'slice.js';

// for array
const arr = slice([1, '2', 3, '4', 5, '6', 7, '8', 9, '0']);

arr['2:5'];        // [3, '4', 5]
arr[':-2'];        // [1, '2', 3, '4', 5, '6', 7, '8']
arr['-2:'];        // [9, '0']
arr['1:5:2'];      // ['2', '4']
arr['5:1:-2'];     // ['6', '4']

// for string
const str = slice('1234567890');
str['2:5'];        // '345'
str[':-2'];        // '12345678'
str['-2:'];        // '90'
str['1:5:2'];      // '24'
str['5:1:-2'];     // '64'
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49152041/edit) your answer to explain how this piece of code answers the question and maybe why this would be better than the currently accepted answer.

Comment: I reckon it's a legit alternative response. It provides a way to accomplish what the querent is asking, whilst allowing them to stay within their comfort zone.

Comment: Yeah, but not without installing an external library. How do you accomplish this via vanilla JS?

Answer (score 4):

## SLICE

> Slice is a JavaScript implementation of Python's awesome negative
>   indexing and extended slice syntax for arrays and strings. It uses ES6
>   proxies to allow for an intuitive double-bracket indexing syntax which
>   closely replicates how slices are constructed in Python. Oh, and it
>   comes with an implementation of Python's range method too!

I know a package that solves this exact problem.

It's called

[image]

you can **literally** do with arrays and string whatever you do in python.

to install this package:

```
yarn add slice
// or
npm install slice
```

---

### Simple use cases

check out [→ the docs ←](https://github.com/intoli/slice/blob/master/README.md) for more.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Or you could use substr

```
s2 = s1.substr(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

just change

```
console.log(s2.slice(1,-1));
```

for

```
console.log(s2.slice(1,s2.length));
```

You can check further info on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```js
var s2 = "stackoverflow";
alert(s2.slice(1, s2.length));
```

Comment: Both indices (parameters) are _zero-based_. So your code is incorrect. In order to get `'w'` (as OP want), `s2.slice(-1)` should be used.

Comment: it works for the desired output: tackoverflow, as you can see on the edit. And it provide the same output as the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

If you need the step argument here is a solution

```js
Array.prototype.slice_ = function(start,end,step=1) {
    return this.slice(start,end)
        .reduce((acc, e, i) => i % step == 0 
        ? [...acc, e] 
        : acc, []); 
}
console.log([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].slice_(1, 10, 2))
```